# How to make a div width flexible?

Tags: html, css-float

I have 2 div's sitting side by side.I will populate the two div's with text from database.Now, the div on L.H.S may or may not have text inside it.On the other hand the div on R.H.S. will always have text inside it.My problem is ; how do i design the R.H.S div in such a way that when there be no text in the L.H.S div then it would grow to 100% dynamically and if there be text in L.H.S div then it would resize to its original width of 50%.

My div's looks like:

```
<div id="left" style="float:right;width:50%;background-color:yellow;">
    Left content
</div>
<div id="right" style="float:right;width:50%;background-color:red;">
    Right content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS selectors:

```
<div id="left">Left content</div>
<div id="right">Right content</div>
```

CSS

```
#left, #right {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    background:#eee;
    width:50%;
}

#left:empty {
    width:0;
}

#left:empty + #right {
    width:100%;
}
```

**[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/pd4ads4v/)**

please note: for `:empty` to work, there has to be nothing in your div, not even a space.

Comment: Wow!!! it works the way i want it to.....but on the downside, the above css affects other div's on the page. how do i stop that?

Comment: I've updated my answer so that the CSS is more specific. If there are going to be more of these areas in your HTML, you may want to consider using classes.